# php/sql writing to csv file , too many results

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to write a result set to a .csv. Writing to the file is working fine, no issue there. 
The problem is its writing the entire table contents not just the result set returned.
The echo outputs the correct results.
Where am I going wrong here? Its driving me nuts ... 
I've tried writing to an array and stepping through it and its still outputting all table contents.

```
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_database", $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die ($e->getMessage());
        $sql = "SELECT userid, tasksdateid, jobid, taskid, timeid, dateid FROM tbl_report WHERE userid = 'test@sip.com'";

        $fpCSV = fopen('resultsexport.csv', 'w');
        foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
            echo "<tr><td>".$row['jobid']."</td><td>".$row['userid']."</td><td>".$row['tasksdateid']."</td><td>".$row['taskid']."</td><td>".$row['timeid']."</td><td>".$row['dateid']."</td></tr>";
            $forCSV = "'".$row['jobid']."','".$row['userid']."','".$row['tasksdateid']."','".$row['taskid']."','".$row['timeid']."','".$row['dateid']."'\n";
            fputcsv($fpCSV, split(',', $forCSV));
        }
        fclose($fpCSV);
```

Thanks!

***EDIT - SOLVED*** 
All this trouble was caused by this line in the html header!! :

```
    <link rel="icon" href="">
```

Gah! Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: The echo and csv lines are distinctly different. Where are the $jobidresult, $taskidresult, $hours, $minutes (which echo line does not include) coming from? Are any of them arrays? Please show their assignment so we can help.

Comment: Gah, apologies, that was a version I was using to test another method. The intended version of the csv line there now. thanks!

Comment: Just to add, if I insert the following echo after the csv line it lists the records correctly on screen (as does the echo line)  :  echo $forCSV."<br>";

Comment: Is this code wrapped under another loop as I see padded space on left? I ask because I can't recreate issue pulling mock data from my database sources. Can you post how output looks and desired output as *writing the entire table contents not just the result set returned* is not too clear. Is it repeating data? How can it write entire table when you query a portion?

Comment: no not in another loop just padded for ?>
</body>
</html>          the output to the .csv is just a listing of exactly the contents of the tbl_report , I know... its a bit nuts, I've never encountered it before. The echo posts the desired output as queried... it doesn't make any sense. :-/

Comment: You mean csv outputs entire tblreport without the `WHERE` clause filter? Cannot be. Please check your post here matches actual code.

Comment: I cannot see how HTML markup has anything to do with server-side PHP from processing. If only we could have seen what your undesired results looked like. Future readers may benefit with seeing the problem. Do answer your own question to resolve.

Comment: "If only we could have seen what your undesired results looked like"  - As I mentioned in my first post, its was the entire contents of the table, it didn't matter what the values were... it dumped all rows to the .csv . I haven't figured out why this happened due to the line I quoted yet... its still a mystery to me :-(